# Properties of finite semigroup $S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

> > Let $S$ be a finite semigroup and $T$ be a subset of $S$ which satisfy the property for any $x, y \in T$, there exist $a \in S$ such that  $x, y \in \langle a \rangle$. Is $\langle T \rangle$ a monogenic subsemigroup of $S$.

I have tried by induction, but I stuck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you mean $x\cdot y$ instead of $x,y$ in your second listing of them?

Comment: I mean that every two element $x, y \in T$ generates a monogenic subsemigroup of $S$. This is  right which I have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Take $S = \{a, a^2, a^3 \}$ with $a^3 = a^4$ and $T = \{a^2, a^3\}$.

**EDIT**. As observed by user120386, this example has to be modified as follows: $S = \{a, a^2, a^3, a^4 \}$ with $a^4 = a^5$ and $T = \{a^2, a^3\}$. Then $\langle T \rangle = \{a^2, a^3, a^4\} \subseteq \langle a \rangle$, but $\langle a^2 \rangle = \{a^2, a^4 \}$ and $\langle a^3 \rangle = \{a^3, a^4 \}$, and thus $\langle T \rangle$ is not monogenic.

Comment: @ J.E Pin : If  we take $T$ is a maximal subset of $S$ which satisfy the given properties.  Now, is $T$ forms a subsemigroup.

Comment: @ J.E Pin : In your example, I think,  $T = \langle a^2 \rangle$. Please verify it.

Comment: @ J.E Pin :  If $S = \{a, a^2, a^3, a^4, a^5 \}$ with $a^6 = a^5$ and $T  = \{a^2, a^3\}$  which is working.

Comment: @user120386 My bad, you are perfectly right. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ J.E Pin :  In my first comment, the statement is true or not.  I would be thankful if you gave my any hint or any counter example.

Comment: @user120386 As I said, your first comment was perfectly right. If you assume that $a^3 = a^4$, then $\langle a^2 \rangle = \{a^2, a^4\} = \{a^2, a^3\}$. Your second comment was also right, but if I am not wrong this time, the slightly smaller example given in the EDIT suffices. Thank you again for your very useful comments.

Comment: Sir, First thanks for consider my comment and I want to prove that If $T$ is a maximal subset of $S$ which satisfy the properties given in the question, then $T$ is a subsemigroup of $S$. But  I am unable to prove. So if possible for you, gave  me any hint how to prove this.

Comment: @user120386 Comments are not the right place to ask/answer a new question. Why don't you ask your question on this site? It will have a larger audience and it will be more convenient to answer it.